Cannot scrape content and not getting NoSuchElementException
I have the following code (hopefully it should be a copy paste if you've got web driver set up in your PATH variable)
public void scrape() {
        System.out.println("Starting Scrape!");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.get(url);
        WebElement until = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("eui-block-content__wrapper")));
        //The results have been loaded now

        //Click on accept cookie page:
        new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3
        )).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Accept all cookies"))).click();

        String moreButton = "/html/body/app-root/ecl-app/div[2]/app-search-page/app-search-container/div/div/section/div/app-elec-display-search-result/app-search-result/eui-block-content/div/app-search-result-item[1]/article/div[3]/div/a";
        String xPathBrandName = "/html/body/app-root/ecl-app/div[2]/app-search-page/app-search-container/div/div/section/div/app-elec-display-search-result/app-search-result/eui-block-content/div/app-search-result-item[1]/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/span[1]";
        String xPathSDR = "/html/body/app-root/ecl-app/div[2]/app-search-page/app-search-container/div/div/section/div/app-elec-display-search-result/app-search-result/eui-block-content/div/app-search-result-item[1]/article/div[2]/div/app-elec-display-search-result-parameters/app-search-parameter-item[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/span";

        //Clicking on more button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(moreButton)).click();

        WebElement brandName = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPathBrandName));
        WebElement SDR = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPathSDR));

        System.out.println("Brand name: " + brandName.getText());
        System.out.println("SDR name: " + SDR.getText());
    }

I am unable to scrape the text of "SDR". When i go to the website on chrome and paste the xpath to see if it is correct, Chrome is able to find the element it leads to (which is how i got the xpath in the first place).
I don't get a NoSuchElementException so it does mean that the element exists. This is the site. The site is built with AJAX requests as it's pretty dyanamic but the fact I am able to get the model name but not the "SDR" seems pretty weird.
